# I'm trying to follow a python tutorial but keep getting error zsh: command not found: from

Tags: python, python-3.x, apple-m1, macos-ventura

I have a M1 Ventura 13.3 mac. I've seen this problem listed elsewhere but none of those answers worked for me. I'm at the point in the tutorial where it says to type in "from django.db import models" This is when I get the zsh: command not found : from I am in a virtual environment as the tutorial instructed.

I found a suggestion to check the version of python. The terminal and vs code appeared to be using different versions of python and wouldn't let me change it. Then I decided I would uninstall reinstall python as I had multiple versions. I uninstalled anaconda, the python extensions from vs code, and the python listed in applications. I reinstalled and followed some instructions I found. I still had the multiple versions but this time it let me change the one in VS Code. They are now both on python 3.10.9 but no change. Yesterday I tried to follow some instructions about the .zshch? file and realized how much I don't know what I'm doing. This is my first mac and before this I worked 6 years in windows tech support. So I don't know if this is a mac, python, or vs code problem. I hope I've given enough information that someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to type the commands directly into the shell rather than a python prompt. You will get better answers if you describe how to reproduce the error you are seeing (i.e. what exactly are you doing to get this error).

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful to run commands in the Python REPL rather than in the terminal shell.

```
(base) user@user-pc:~$ from django.db import models # the error will be different in mac os
from: too many arguments
(base) user@user-pc:~$ python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 19:58:26) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django.db import models
>>> # no output means success
```